# On the permissability of uncountable languages in constructions of FOL

Tags: first-order-logic, meta-math

To me it has always been a leap in allowing uncountable languages in constructions of first-order logic. I do my best to avoid them. Unfortunately this is not always possible. I was curious if anyone could show/justify/prove that it's possible to assign a unique symbol/graphic to each real number. It would be helpful in easing my hesitance in accepting the current proof I'm reading.

Comment: Why are uncountable *languages* any more confusing than uncountable *sets*? They're just formal objects, there's no assertion that the "symbols" are actually symbols in the graphical sense; this is identical to how we work with arbitrary (say) real numbers without asking whether they have any physical meaning.

Comment: "Languages are intended to be scribable." No, they're not, any more than sets are intended to be countable. A language is a purely formal object, there is no physicality assumed about it.

Comment: "and a graphical method by which one can proof something using rules of inference." No, it isn't. Logic isn't only a tool mathematicians use to write proofs in - it's also a mathematical object in its own right. Just as not every real number "occurs in nature" (ok it's unclear exactly what that means, but the point should make sense), not every language "is scribable."

Comment: "The term "Language" in the context of constructing a first-order theory, refers to a set of constants, function symbols, and relation symbols that are designed to be put on paper at some point in the process." **No**, it's not! While that's the *motivation*, it's not actually part of the definition, any more than we require that for any positive real number we should be able to draw a line of that length. "Language" (in the first-order context) *just* means "a set of constant symbols, function symbols, and relation symbols."

Comment: @Noah Schweber Thank you for your feedback Noah. I appreciate it. I probably should have given more context to the actual reason this question popped up.

Answer (score 1):

The idea that "a language is a set of scribable symbols" is similar to the idea that "a positive real number is the length of physical object" - it gets things started nicely, but you very quickly want to discard it in favor of a purely abstract treatment.

That is: there is a distinction between "language humans can use" and "language as a mathematical object." Logic is not just a *tool*, but also a *subject of mathematical inquiry itself*. You will certainly never actually write using a language with continuum-many (or indeed infinitely many, or even Graham's-number-many) symbols, but that doesn't mean you won't study such languages.

If you prefer, you can make new names for everything: planguage, psymbol, pstructure, ... (the "p" is silent). I **don't** mean this dismissively - one may reasonably object to the use of the word "language" to describe something that can't be written down (similarly, I think some ultrafinitists object to the term "number" being used to describe e.g. Graham's number), and so it may be helpful at least at first to translate theorems about logic into an un-loaded terminology.

---

I think at this point it's useful to give a definition of a structure - complete with its language - as a purely mathematical object. The following definition (made inside your favorite set theory or other foundational framework - I'll use ZFC for simplicity) might help clarify things:

- A *structure* is a triple $(A, \Sigma, I)$ where

  - $A$ is an arbitrary set (the underlying set of the structure),
  - $\Sigma$ is some function with codomain $\mathbb{N}$ (we think of $\Sigma$ itself as the language: the symbols are the ordered pairs $\langle x, \Sigma(x)\rangle$ for $x\in dom(\Sigma)$ - note that set-theoretically speaking, $\Sigma$ itself is exactly the set of all such ordered pairs! - where the left coordinate is giving the symbol a name and the right coordinate is giving it an arity), and
  - $I$ is a map from $dom(\Sigma)$ to $\mathcal{P}(A)\cup \mathcal{P}(A^2)\cup\mathcal{P}(A^3)\cup...$ such that $\Sigma(d)=i$ implies $I(d)\in\mathcal{P}(A^i)$. ($I$ is the interpretation of the symbols in the domain of $\Sigma$, sending each symbol to a relation on $A$ of appropriate arity.)

So for example, let's say I want to look at "$\mathbb{R}$ with each real named by a unary relation symbol." One way to view this is as the structure $$(\mathbb{R}, \{\langle r, 1\rangle: r\in\mathbb{R}\}, \{\langle r, \{r\}\rangle: r\in\mathbb{R}\}\}).$$ That is:

- The underlying set is $\mathbb{R}$.
- We have one unary relation symbol for each real number.
- The interpretation of the unary relation symbol indexed by "$r$" is $\{r\}$.

(Remember that in set theory, a function is a set of ordered pairs.)

Note that each real is doing double-duty here, both as an element of the structure and as a (left coordinate of a) symbol. This is fine as long as we're careful about it, but it's also reasonable to demand that the domain of $\Sigma$ and the underlying set of the structure be disjoint, just to make things nicer. In this case, we could work instead with $$(\mathbb{R}, \{\langle \langle r, \mathbb{R}\rangle, 1\rangle: r\in\mathbb{R}\}, \{\langle \langle r, \mathbb{R}\rangle, \{r\}\rangle: r\in\mathbb{R}\}).$$ That is, each symbol's left coordinate is now *itself an ordered pair* of the form $\langle r,\mathbb{R}\rangle$; in any reasonable set theory, no such ordered pair is a real number, so this meets the additional requirement.

We can now define formulas, sentences, theories, satisfaction, ultraproducts, etc. for arbitrary languages (that is, functions with codomain $\mathbb{N}$) and arbitrary structures on purely mathematical grounds, and prove theorems about these. How you choose to *interpret* these definitions and theorems, philosophically speaking, is to a certain extent up to you. But it's important to note that they interact in nice ways with the more "concrete" objects: e.g. we can prove something about a "concrete structure" (say, the field of real numbers) by proving something about an "abstract structure" (say, an appropriate ultrapower of the field of real numbers).

Comment: I've seen this construction Noah. The context that I'm approaching this in will not permit this approach. I am not a novice to formal logic. I appreciate your passion and response. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidReed " The context that I'm approaching this in will not permit this approach." OK, what context is that? I might be able to help if I know more about it. (And I apologize if this came off as condescending; I'll leave it up as it may be useful to other readers less familiar with this material, who will be attracted by the title/body of the question.)

Comment: Sure, let me see if I can send it to you somehow. It's in an encrypted ebook but my guess is I will be able to screenshot it.

Comment: For other readers: One common context in which something like this might come up is in encoding "the theory of $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces" as a first-order theory.  The encoding is that for each $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ we have a formal symbol $SM_\lambda$ representing a function $V \to V$ which we think of as scalar multiplication by $\lambda$ (and then as a convenience notation we tend to write $SM_\lambda(x)$ as $\lambda \cdot x$).

Comment: Then, of course, there would be a binary function symbol "+", a zero vector symbol "0", a unary function symbol "-" for negation, etc.  And axioms would include things like $SM_\lambda(SM_\mu(x)) = SM_{\lambda \cdot \mu}(x)$, $SM_{\lambda + \mu}(x) = SM_\lambda(x) + SM_\mu(x)$, etc.

Comment: @DavidReed Sure, definitely no hurry. (Even just knowing the theorem you're trying to prove would help, btw.)

Comment: Basically a work-around of Los' for the transfer theorem for the hyperreals. This book is ancient but I prefer its approach overall.

Comment: @DavidReed Well, why do you want a proof avoiding uncountable languages? This seems like the archetypical pstructures result. Just view it entirely as being on the abstract, rather than concrete, side of the divide.