# How does the extended language $\mathcal{L}({\mathfrak{A}})$ over a structure $\mathfrak{A}$ work exactly?

Tags: logic

As title states, I'm a tiny bit confused as to how the standard extension of a language $\mathcal{L}$ into $\mathcal{L}(\mathfrak{A})$ over a given structure $\mathfrak{A}$ works exactly.

As I've seen it (and this seemed totally intuitive to me up till now), $\mathcal{L}(\mathfrak{A})$ simply is built off $\mathcal{L}$ + constant symbols $\overline{a}$ for each $a \in |\mathfrak{A}|$, i.e., $\mathcal{L}(\mathfrak{A}) = \mathcal{L} \cup \{\overline{a} : a \in |\mathfrak{A}|\}$.

Thinking about it more, how exactly does $\{\overline{a} : a \in |\mathfrak{A}|\}$ work, though? How do we "add" one *symbol* $\overline{a}$ for each *object* $a \in |\mathfrak{A}|$? Doesn't this require that we have a *representation* $a$ for each object $a \in |\mathfrak{A}|$ so that we can add a line over it and get $\overline{a}$?

$\{a : a \in |\mathfrak{A}|\}$ is just a set with objects of $|\mathfrak{A}|$ in it, those very objects need not have a particular representation each. With something like the naturals $n \in \mathbb{N}$, it seems intuitive enough how to construct each respective $\overline{n}$, but what exactly is going on with something like $\{\overline{r} : r \in \mathbb{R}\}$?

I'm not sure if I've expressed my problem clearly enough (or if it even is one) but I hope what I'm trying to get at can perhaps be seen.

Comment: Yes, intuitively we add a *name* for each *object*, e.g. a name (a [numeral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_(linguistics))) for each natural number. In order to avoid confusion between objects of the structure (we use symbols like $a$ for them) and the corresponding names of the extended language, we denote the symbol with the overline. Thus $\overline a$ is the symbol added to the language that corersponds to object $a$.

Comment: Regarding $\mathbb B$, maybe useful [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2554776/on-the-permissability-of-uncountable-languages-in-constructions-of-fol).

Comment: And see [Computability & Logic](https://www.jeffreyheinz.net/classes/17F/materials/Boolos%20et%20al%205th%20Edition%20Computability%20and%20Logic%20Chaps%201-2.pdf), page 117 for an approach that circumvent the non-denumerable case.

Comment: See the quote from Hodges in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4730322/7062), especially the last paragraph.